# execute batch file works fine when executed manually but not when scheduling it

Tags: excel, batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have this batch file :

```
cd "C:\Users\test\Desktop\soft\" 
Start excel "AD Monitor Auto Run.xlsm"
```

when I execute it manually it works fine but when Run it in a scheduler task  i get this error message :

```
'C:\Users\test\Desktop\soft\AD' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: won't solve your problem, but you should use `cd` with parameter /d, this will also change the drive (see `cd /?`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:  the leading `""` is needed in a start command in your case.
Verify that the path is correct too.

```
Start "" excel "C:\Users\test\Desktop\soft\AD Monitor Auto Run.xlsm"
```

Comment: Try the solution I suggested above: I just edited it as there was a cd in it I missed out on removing.

Comment: another problem, I need the task to be executed even when I'm not logged-on, i remark that the task don't Run when I check the box "Run whether user is logged on or not"

Comment: Open another question - I think SuperUser might be a better forum for this too.